# Create JSON string containing a List object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am posting a JSON string to a controller method that accepts an object I created. The object has two properties: a List of ints, and a string. I want to create the JSON string in js to post to the controller via AJAX. I can't find a way to create the List dynamically in JSON though.

Here's where I want to build the JSON

```
    var ApplicantIDs = [];
    var RejectionReason = $("#SelectedRejectReason").val();
    ApplicantIDs = $("#RejectIDs").val();
    var Rejection;
    jQuery.each(ApplicantIDs, function(i) {

        //add ApplicantIDs to Rejection object
    });

    //add RejectionReason to Rejection object

    RejectApplicants(Rejection);
```

Here's the AJAX post

```
 function RejectApplicants(Rejection) {

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("RejectApplicants", "Home")',
        data: JSON.stringify(Rejection),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.redirectTo == null) {
                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Error", "Home")';
            } else {
                alert("All selected applicants exported succesfully!");
                window.location.href = data.redirectTo;
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Error", "Home")';
        }
    });

}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RejectApplicants(Rejection myRejection)
```

And my Rejection Object

```
public class Rejection
{
    public List<int> ApplicantIDs { get; set; }
    public string RejectionReason { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just declare the object, like this:

```
var Rejection = {
    RejectionReason: $("#SelectedRejectReason").val(),
    ApplicantIDs: $("#RejectIDs").val().split(',')
};

RejectApplicants(Rejection);
```

Comment: The value of $("#RejectIDs").val() is a string of comma separated ints. It doesn't convert it to a List<int> when it gets posted, it comes over with nothing in the list, but the RejectionReason is populated. How does it know that ApplicantIDs is an array here?

Comment: You have to split the string; `$('#RejectIDs').val().split(',')`.